# Error: Permission denied to access property "rejection" in angler 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting "Error: Permission denied to access property "rejection"" error in angler 2. Please see below image:

**Screenshot of Firefox**

[image]

**Screenshot of Chrome**
[image]

I have added below code in **services.js** file

```
getFooter(){
    return this.http.get(this.cons.footer)
      .map(response => response.json());
}
```

I have used below code in component file

```
ngOnInit(){ 
this._pageService.getFooter()
.subscribe(
            data => this.data =  data.data, 
            error => console.log(error)
        ); 
}
```

I am using below json file.

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "qwqw":"qqq",
        "footer_column_first": [
            "Alien Education",
            "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley. ",
            [
                [
                    "http://facebook.com",
                    "uploads/453085f6fb34252eeb15e26c381daf9b.jpg"
                ],
                [
                    "http://twitter.com",
                    "uploads/8c542d463e812318f71271a41850fd41.jpg"
                ],
                [
                    "http://linkedin.com",
                    "uploads/c29507573b1434ae96783c749248d958.jpg"
                ],
                [
                    "http://youtube.com",
                    "uploads/e311b879e07c9a6a8c924f758566e28f.jpg"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I have used blow code in template (".html"). but I am getting below error

```
{{ console.log(data.qwqw) }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data?.qwqw
```

use question mark in variable 
it will make sure that `var` is not undefined

Comment: Why `data` is not getting here?  I am already passing `data` viable.

Comment: angular trying to render template before data assigned to variable

Comment: Can you please explain, How it is working? If you have any document please let me know.